# How to add my graphic design portfolio files(.PSD) as a download within an android/IOS app?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I'd like to know how to add my graphic design portfolio files(.PSD) as downloadable files within an android/IOS app using flutter? The app I'm creating will show my portfolio work as an image with a download button below the portfolio image which will then give the user a download(preferably a .PSD file) which they can add to their phone storage via a save to location or whatever it's called on android/IOS.

I'm only asking in theory at the moment. As I don't know where to start in regards to storing my .PSD files within the app I'd like to create.